# error:NullInjectorError: No provider for Router

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-providers

I have to test one component  and get this error NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthenticationService -> Router -> Router]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!**"
The component I'm testing have two dependencies and I don't know hot to provide both them in the test with testbed
**gallery.component.ts**

```
constructor( private authService:AuthenticationService, private iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers){
        this.iterableDiffer = iterableDiffers.find([]).create(null);
    }
```

**gallery.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('GalleryComponent', () => {

    let component: GalleryComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<GalleryComponent>
    let authServiceMock: AuthenticationService
    let iterableDifferMock: IterableDiffers

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers:[GalleryComponent, {provide:AuthenticationService}, {provide:IterableDiffers}]
    })
        

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GalleryComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        authServiceMock = TestBed.inject(AuthenticationService)
    })
...
```

how to provide both dependencies?
I read the Angular DOC and I didn't find the solution, I sew other asks on SO but without find solutions.
Thanks

Comment: thanks for reply but I don't want test routing. gallery.component is not a route, it is a child of container.component.

Comment: ok done! now i have another error "[AuthenticationService -> AuxiliarService -> Store -> Store]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!"

Comment: i provide "{provide:AuthenticationService, useValue:authServiceMock}" done, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just import `RouterTestingModule` to your imports array in the TestBed

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  providers:[
    GalleryComponent, 
    {provide:AuthenticationService}, 
    {provide:IterableDiffers}
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just inject every dependency you have in the component's constructor:

```
constructor( private authService:AuthenticationService, private iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers){}
```

If you need to use Angular router too:

```
constructor( private authService:AuthenticationService, private iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers, private router: Router){}
```

And no need to add:

```
this.iterableDiffer = iterableDiffers.find([]).create(null);
```

Afterwards, you can just call and work with the dependency you want.